# svg foreignObject wrap background not follow width,height

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

As title,i want my text can wrap so i use "foreignObject".
the code is success but too many white space.
here's the result image:
[image]

here's the code:

```
json_data.forEach(function(d) {
            var elemEnter = svg.select("g")
                .append('g')
                .attr("transform", d.transform);

            elemEnter.append('circle')
                .attr("r", d.r)
                .attr("fill", d.fill = "red")
                .attr("class", d.class)
                .attr("id", "node_id" + d.node_sn)
                .attr("onclick", "NodesDownInlv3(" + d.node_sn + ")");


            elemEnter.append('foreignObject')
                .attr("class",d.class)
                .attr("id", "node_id_text" + d.node_sn)
                .attr("style", "text-anchor:middle")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return -60;
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return 30;
                })
                .attr("width",150)
                .attr("height",50)
                .append('xhtml:body')
                .append('p')
                .attr("id", "node_id" + d.node_sn)
                .text("(5-n-11)123456789,abcdefgh");
        });
```

Comment: I've no idea what you're asking here. The foreignObject is as high as its height attribute.

Comment: My question is how to let foreignObject don't show too many white space.

Comment: reduce its height and/or width.

Comment: when i try to reduce 'height' still have white space. but if i set 'width' value is 0 there's no white space. but the text'll vertical.